# How to pass value to a method in a method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn how jquery can select an element pick an attribute and set it to a value. I have figured out how to select the element and pick an attribute. I just cant seem to set the attribute via a parameter.

This is the format that jquery uses. As i am trying to replicate

```
onclick='$(this).innerHTML("My new Text")'
```

I am trying to change the innerHTML of a button when i click it to "My new Text" or any other value.

I have came up with this from what i understand.

```
var $ = function(obj)
{
    var innerHTML = function(obj)
    {
        obj.innerHTML = **NEED HELP HERE**;
    }(obj);
};
```

How can i read the argument (in this case "My new Text") from the innerHTML() call?

Thanks

Comment: do you need the innerHtml call?  can't you use jQuery's attr or prop methods?

Comment: I think that OP trying to mimic jQuery functions, for learning purposes. Btw, innerHTML is native js function, so, why not create another?

Comment: Yes @nevermind that's what i'm trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` needs to return an object so you can access its `.innerHTML` property. That function takes the HTML text as an argument, it accesses the element using a closure variable from the `$` function.

```
$ = function(element) {
    return {
        innerHTML: function(html) {
            element.innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You sir are a savior. Such little code and now my understatement of JavaScript is magnitudes higher.